# Why is this value reactive if it's not declared in data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope, vuejs2

I need to store some values in a Vue Component `beforeCreate` hook that I'll require later in `beforeDestroy`. The thing is (or at least that's what I understood) `beforeCreate` hook doesn't have access to reactive `data` yet.

Since I don't need these values anywhere but in `beforeDestroy`, I don't mind them not being reactive, so I'm good with that. But at the end, when I try:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  data: function() { return { msg: "I'm a reactive value." }},
  template: '<div><div>{{ msg }}</div> <div>{{value}}</div> <button @click="onClick">Click Me</button></div>',
  beforeCreate: function() { this.value = "I was declared before data existed." },
  methods: {
    onClick: function(event) {
      this.msg += " So, I respond to changes.";
      this.value += " But I'm still reactive... (?)";
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-component />
</div>
```

it looks like the value **is** reactive after all...

1. What am I missing here?
2. Is there any possible secondary effect that I should consider when adding data to `this` in `beforeCreate`?

Comment: Those are just properties on the object; that behavior is completely consistent with the basic way JavaScript works.

Comment: @Pointy I don't understand what you mean. If I have a plain JS object and I render it in my DOM and later I update some keys of my object, the DOM isn't automatically updated. Vue takes care of that, but I thought it only did it for `data`, `computed` properties, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reactivity is with `this.msg`, not `this.value`

Your confusion seems to come from a misconception about how Vue updates the DOM when reactive data changes:

You seem to think that, if you change `this.msg`, then Vue would selectively only update those parts of the DOM where `msg` was used. That's not the case.

What really happens is this:

1. When *any* reactive dependency of the template (here: `this.msg`) changes, the virtualDOM for the *whole* component is being re-rendered.
2. This means that in this process, `{{ value }}` is being re-evaluated, and since you also changed it, its new value is now part of the new virtualDOM.
3. Then Vue makes a diff of the old and new virtualDOM and patches the real DOM with any changes it found.
4. Since you changed both `{{ msg }}` and `{{ value }}`, both of the `<div>` elements containing those references will be patched with the new content.

So you see `this.value` itself is not reactive - but if you change it and also make a reactive change alongside it, the new value will be included in the component's update.

To see that `this.value` is not reactive, just comment out the change for `this.msg`:

```
// this.msg += " So, I respond to changes.";
this.value += " But I'm still reactive... (?)";
```

Comment: Btw, about my 2) question. Do you think I should avoid doing that or it's ok?

Comment: Yeah it's fine to do that. Just keepn an eye on naming, it shouldn't collide with any data/computed/methods obviuosly. Besides that this is a totally fine thing to do.